# Applying a clock in quantum computing?

Tags: classical-computing

In quantum computing, I feel it mostly looks like designing hardware with Hardware Description Language (HDL) experience such as VHDL or Verilog.

So the term program language for quantum computing such as QASM (Quantum Assembly) I prefer say it as Quantum HDL than QASM. In assembly, everything is sequential processing. While HDL may faster than assembly due to able processing data using combinational logic instead of sequential logic.

Clock is basic of sequential computing. The most basic program of sequential computing is binary counter which count binary number from $0$ to $2^{n_{bit}}-1$ every time unit.

So how do you implement binary counter in quantum computing?

Will you just put all qubits with hadamard gate as an input as a replace binary counter? If so, then the data will not processed sequentially from $0$ to $2^{n_{bit}}-1$ because every shot of experiment the result maybe random hence result I will see is just probability diagram.